# Python Screen Scraping Forbes.com

Tags: python, redirect, web-scraping

I'm writing a Python program to extract and store metadata from interesting online tech articles: "og:title", "og:description", "og:image", og:url, and og:site_name.

This is the code I'm using...

```
# Setup Headers
headers = {}
headers['Accept'] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
headers['Accept-Charset'] = 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'none'
headers['Accept-Language'] = "en-US,en;q=0.8"
headers['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36"

# Create the Request
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

# Create the Response
response = http.request('GET ', url, headers)

# BeautifulSoup - Construct
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, 'html.parser')

# Scrape <meta property="og:title" content=" x x x ">
if tag.get("property", None) == "og:title":
   if len(tag.get("content", None)) > len(title):
      title = tag.get("content", None)
```

The program runs fine on all but one site. On "forbes.com", I can't get to the articles using Python:

url= 
https://www.forbes.com/consent/?toURL=https://www.forbes.com/sites/shermanlee/2018/07/31/privacy-revolution-how-blockchain-is-reshaping-our-economy/#72c3b4e21086

I can't bypass this consent page; which seems to be the "Cookie Consent Manager" solution from "TrustArc". On a computer, you basically provide your consent... and each consecutive run, you're able to access the articles.

If I reference the "toURL" url: 
https://www.forbes.com/sites/shermanlee/2018/07/31/privacy-revolution-how-blockchain-is-reshaping-our-economy/#72c3b4e21086

And bypass the "https://www.forbes.com/consent/" page, I'm redirected back to this page.

I've tried to see if there is a cookie I could set in the header, but couldn't find the magic key.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is a required cookie `notice_gdpr_prefs` that needs to be sent to view the data :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

src = requests.get(
    "https://www.forbes.com/sites/shermanlee/2018/07/31/privacy-revolution-how-blockchain-is-reshaping-our-economy/",
    headers= {
        "cookie": "notice_gdpr_prefs"
    })

soup = BeautifulSoup(src.content, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find("meta",  property="og:title")
print(title["content"])
```

Comment: Thanks. What should be the value of that cookie? Isn't the convention normally "cookie": "notice_gdpr_prefs=SOMEVALUE"?

Comment: I did some testing and noticed the content is like this "0,1,2:<hex:uuid>" and a second cookie (baring the same name) "2:<the same hex:uuid>". If I parse these in the headers (even using the uuid I copy/pasted from my brower cookie), I'm still not getting to the website. :(